# A variation of closed-subgroup theorem

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, lie-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$Recall that the *closed-subgroup theorem* ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem)) says that a closed subgroup of a Lie group is a Lie group.

I am pretty sure that this theorem should have a "local" generalisation. I'll formulate it for $\SO(n)$.

**Generalisation?**  Fix small $\varepsilon>0$. Let $X\subset \SO(n)$ be a closed subset contained in the closed ball $\overline B_{e}(\varepsilon)$ centred at the identity $e$ of $\SO(n)$. Suppose $X$ has the following properties.

1. $X=X^{-1}$.
2. $X\cdot X\cdot X\cdot X\cap \overline B_{e}(\varepsilon)=X$.

Then there exists a Lie group an $G$, a morphism  $\varphi: G\to \SO(n)$ and a finite subset $S\subset \SO(n)$ such that $$X=\overline B_{e}(\varepsilon)\cap S\cdot \varphi(\overline B_{G,e}(10 \varepsilon)),$$

where $\overline B_{G,e}(10 \varepsilon)$ is a small ball in $G$. In particular, $X$ is a submanifold of the ball (with finite number of connected components).

Are you aware of some statement of this kind? (the power $4$ is random, maybe it should be replaced by some other power)

Comment: What if (a trite example) $X = \{(x, \sqrt{2}x) : x \in [-\epsilon, \epsilon]\} \subset \mathbf{T}^2$ (and the torus is embedded in $\mathrm{SO}(n)$)?

Comment: Dear Sean, thanks! This is indeed a counter-example, but it am not afraid of it. I'll modify the question so that there is still a meaning, which is good enough for me

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP is modifying the question.  In the original question, the OP did not ask that the Lie subgroup $G\subset \mathrm{SO}(n)$ be compact, i.e., closed, just that it exist, and the 'skew-line' that Sean writes down is obviously part of a (non-closed) Lie subgroup.  Did the OP mean to require that $G$ be a closed Lie subgroup?

Comment: @RobertBryant The problem is that the non-compact skew line still doesn't work, because its intersection with a nbd of 1 is dense there

Comment: @SeanEberhard:  Ah, you are right.  Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Tao's book on Hilbert's fifth problem -- https://terrytao.wordpress.com/books/hilberts-fifth-problem-and-related-topics/ -- Theorem 3.1.7, where it is referred to as local Cartan's theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean! It looks exactly as what I was looking for.

Comment: The theorem @SeanEberhard mentions is also available in Tao's online version of his notes (perhaps the same as the book?) as Theorem 12 of [Notes 2 - Building Lie structure from representations and metrics](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/08/254a-notes-2-building-lie-structure-from-representations-and-metrics).  It states "If $H$ is a locally compact local subgroup of a local Lie group $G$, then there is an open neighbourhood $H'$ of the identity in $H$ that is a smooth submanifold of $G$, and is thus also a local Lie group."